# Decrypting an AES encrypted column in mysql and adobe flex/flash builder?

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, encryption

How do i decrypt an aes encrypted column when using flash/flex to display the table data?
adobe flex connected using php connection class to mysql

for php, we would use aes_decrypt() 
however i am not sure how i can get flex to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the ActionScript language, but take a look at one of these two libraries:

http://as3crypto.riaforge.org/index.cfm

http://ascrypt3.riaforge.org/index.cfm

I recommend the as3Crypto library first, as it was built from scratch in AS3.  ASCrypt3 was converted from an AS2 library to AS3 (by me).